# how to create new element with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dropzone.js

I have a question about JQuery and a Dropzone plugin.

I have html code like this:

```
<form action="/file-upload" class="dropzone">
  <div class="fallback">
    <input name="file" type="file" multiple />
  </div>
</form>
```

In `dropzone.js` I want to set the `addRemoveLinks: true` and want to styling the link remove file a little bit.

In `dropzone.js` the code is like this.

```
Dropzone.prototype.defaultOptions = {
dictRemoveFile: "Remove file",
    if (this.options.addRemoveLinks) {
            file._removeLink = Dropzone.createElement("<a class=\"dz-remove btn btn-default\" href=\"javascript:undefined;\" data-dz-remove>" + this.options.dictRemoveFile + "</a>");
            file.previewElement.appendChild(file._removeLink);
    }
```

And the result when I do inspect element is:

```
<a class="dz-remove btn btn-default" href="javascript:undefined;" data-dz-remove="">Remove file</a>
```

I just want to make a `div class="custom"` just outside the tag `a`

Example:

```
Dropzone.prototype.defaultOptions = {
    dictRemoveFile: "Remove file",
        if (this.options.addRemoveLinks) {
                file._removeLink = Dropzone.createElement("<div class=\"custom\"><a class=\"dz-remove btn btn-default\" href=\"javascript:undefined;\" data-dz-remove>" + this.options.dictRemoveFile + "</a><div>");
                file.previewElement.appendChild(file._removeLink);
              }
```

But I don't know why. when I try to run it in web browser the link is not clickable. So when I try to inspect element and it only has this:

```
<div class="custom">Remove file</div>
```

Notice the tag `a` is gone.

I try to make the result like this

```
<div class="custom">
<a class="dz-remove btn btn-default" href="javascript:undefined;" data-dz-remove="">Remove file</a>
</div>
```

But it's not working properly.

Comment: van you please create a js fiddle or plunker

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sbxsa4e3/2/ there sir

Comment: can you please confirm if this working
http://jsfiddle.net/sbxsa4e3/4/

Comment: DropzoneJs provide removeTemplate for remove file button use that that i pull request in 2015. Example usages :     `addRemoveLinks : true,
    removeTemplate: "<span class=\"remove\"><i class=\"icon-cross\"></i></span>"`

Comment: sorry  RemoveLinkTemplate is the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with dropzone but based on the code you already have this might work:

```
Dropzone.prototype.defaultOptions = {
    dictRemoveFile: "Remove file",
        if (this.options.addRemoveLinks) {
            file._removeLink = Dropzone.createElement("<a class=\"dz-remove btn btn-default\" href=\"javascript:undefined;\" data-dz-remove>" + this.options.dictRemoveFile + "</a>");
            var custom = Dropzone.createElement("<div class=\"custom\"></div>");
            custom.appendChild(file._removeLink);
            file.previewElement.appendChild(custom);
        }
```

Comment: thanks sir, can i ask you how to create a new element inside tag a? i want to add span glyphicon inside a. can i use it append to?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the confusion and to make code more readable instead of using double quotes for the values of html attribute use single quotes just like:

```
Dropzone.createElement("<a class='dz-remove btn btn-default' href='javascript:undefined;' data-dz-remove=''>Remove file</a>")
```

This way you'll get rid of the backslashes, from that you might see what's wrong with your code.